# MapStruct: How to pass input object to expression?

Tags: mapstruct

In MapStruct version 1.1.0.Final, this was possible....

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(target = "transaction.process.details", expression = "java(MappingHelper.mapDetails(request))"),
     //more mappings
})
Response requestToResponse(Request request);
```

It was possible, since the `mapDetails` method was (by coincidence?) generated into the `requestToResponse` method. That's why `request` was not null.

Now, since 1.1.0.Final didn't work with Lombok, I had to upgrade to 1.2.0.CR2. With this version, the `mapDetails` will be generated into a separate method where `request` is not passed, so `request` is null within this method now and I get a NPE with the expression. (It's a sub-sub-method of `requestToResponse` now.)

Did I misuse the expression, so did it just work by coincidence, or does the new version has a bug? If no bug, how do I have to pass the `request` instance to the expression properly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were / are misusing the expression. What you need to do is to map your target to your source parameter.

```
@Mapper(uses = { MappingHelper.class })
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "transaction.process.details", source = "request"),
         //more mappings
    })
    Response requestToResponse(Request request);
}
```

MapStruct then should create intermediary methods and use the `MappingHelper` and invoke the `mapDetails` method. In case you have multiple methods that map from `Request` to whatever type `details` are then you are going to need to used qualified mappings (see more [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) in the documentation).

It will look something like:

```
public class MappingHelper {
    @Named("mapDetails") // or the better type safe one with the meta annotation @Qualifier
    public static String mapDetails(Request request);
}
```

And your mapping will look like:

```
@Mapper(uses = { MappingHelper.class })
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "transaction.process.details", source = "request", qualifiedByName = "mapDetails"), //or better with the meta annotation @Qualifier qualifiedBy
         //more mappings
    })
    Response requestToResponse(Request request);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you have good tests for this, nested target properties has been enhanced in 1.2.0 and there could be cases where it does not work properly (it was buggy before as well)