# Map multiple fields to one with MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct

I have these 3 classes in separate files

```
public class Book {

   @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String title;

    @NonNull
    private Author author;

}

public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String firstName;

    @NonNull
    private String lastName;

}

public class BookDTO {

    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String title;

    @NonNull
    private String author;

}
```

I have the following mapper

```
@Mapper
public interface BookMapper { 

    BookMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BookMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "author.lastName", target = "author")
    })
    BookDTO toDTO(Book book);

}
```

this currently only maps the lastName and works, and I want to map the author string in Book with

```
author.firstName + " " + author.lastName
```

how could I do that? I have not been able to find anything in the MapStruct Documentation.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

MapSruct does not support mapping multiple source properties into a single target property.

You have 2 ways to achieve this:

#### Using Mapping#expression

```
@Mapping( target = "author", expression = "java(book.getAuthor().getFirstName() + \" \" + book.getAuthor().getLastName())")
```

#### Using `@AfterMapping` or `@BeforeMapping`

```
@Mapper
public interface BookMapper { 

    BookMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BookMapper.class);


    @Mapping(target = "author", ignore = true)
    BookDTO toDTO(Book book);

    @AfterMapping
    default void setBookAuthor(@MappingTarget BookDTO bookDTO, Book book) {
        Author author = book.getAuthor();
        bookDTO.setAuthor(author.getFirstName() + " " + author.getLastName());
    }

}
```

Comment: There is a third way https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309184/1673775

Answer (score 9):

You can also pass the object referenced by the mapper method containing the multiple fields you need as the source fields to a "qualifiedByName" method by referring to the source using a period.

```
@Mapper
public interface BookMapper { 

   @Mapping(target = "author", source = ".", qualifiedByName = "getFullName")
   BookDTO toDTO(Book book);

   @Named("getFullName")
   default String getFullName(Book book) {
       return book.getAuthor().getFirstName() + " " + book.getAuthor().getLastName();
   } 
}
```

Comment: Decent solution, but a method within an interface can't be public. This should be `default`