# Cannot concat 2 fields in MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto, mapstruct

I tried to follow the approach mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722015/map-multiple-fields-to-one-with-mapstruct) page, but could not concat name and surname fields.

Here is what I tried:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PostDtoMapper {

    Post toEntity(PostDto source);

    @Mapping(ignore = true, source = "user", target = "user")
    @Mapping( target = "userName", source = "user.firstName")
    PostDto toDto(Post destination);

    @AfterMapping
    default void toDto(@MappingTarget PostDto postDto, Post post) {
        User user = post.getUser();
        postDto.setUserName(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
    }
}
```

But it only gives the `firstName` value. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remove the following annotation:

```
@Mapping(target = "userName", source = "user.firstName")
```

It is no longer needed because you set this field in *@AfterMapping*

Or even better to replace it with the following:

```
@Mapping(target = "userName", ignore = true)
```

Secondly, check if *user.getLastName()* is not null ;) I have reproduced your example and it is working fine.

Hope it will helps you!

Comment: Interesting, but I think the problem is related to `clean install` command. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, when you run `install` it generates implementations for your mapstruct annotations, therefore if you did not do this before run, it will fail or use previously generated classes

Comment: DO you know how to do in Gradle with skipping tests? I am new for Gradle.

Comment: `gradle build -x test`